# Given an N by M matrix consisting only of 1's and 0's, find the largest rectangle containing only 1's and return its area

Tags: c++

This was an interview question and I have written the answer, but it's not working. Can anyone please suggest an optimized answer or point out my mistake.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void printMaxArea(bool M[R][C]){

int i,j;
int S[R][C];
int maxs,maxi,maxj;
int area=0;
//set 1st column
for(i=0;i<R;i++)
  S[i][0]=M[i][0];
//set 1st row
for(j=0;j<C;j++)
  S[0][j]=M[0][j];
//other entries
for(i=1;i<R;i++){
    for(j=1;j<C;j++){
        if(M[i][j]==1)
          S[i][j]=min(S[i][j-1],min(S[i-1][j],S[i-1][j-1])+1);
        else
          S[i][j]=0;
    }
}
//maximum entry and index
maxs=S[0][0];
maxi=0;
maxj=0;
for(i=0;i<R;i++){
    for(j=0;j<C;j++){
        if(maxs<S[i][j]){
            maxs=S[i][j];
            maxi=i;
            maxj=j;
        }
    }
}   
for(i=maxi;i>maxs-maxi;i--){
    for(j=maxj;j>maxs-maxj;j--){
        area=area+M[i][j];
    }
}
cout<<area;
```

}

```
int main(){

int M[R][C]={{1,0,0,0},
             {1,0,1,1},
             {1,0,1,1},
             {0,1,0,0}};
printMaxArea(M);
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *but it's not working. Can anyone please suggest an optimized answer or point out my mistake.* -- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we are here to help. Let me list up the flaws in this post

- I am not sure, if this was an interview question
- The base answer was given by user rathbhupendra on GeeksForGeeks. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-sub-matrix-with-all-1s-in-a-binary-matrix/?ref=rp)
- Your posted code is a nearly one to one copy from the above linked post from GeeksForGeeks
- Your question text does not match. You are talking about rectangular. The code will work only for square sub-metrices
- Where you did *not* exactly copy and paste, you created the errors. There are 2:

The correct line should be:

```
S[i][j] = min(S[i][j-1],min( S[i-1][j], S[i-1][j-1])) + 1;
```

See the +1 at then end. You put it in brackets.

The second error is in the last for llop, where you calculate the sum. You made a copy and past error in the loop condition. The correct code is

```
    for(i = max_i; i > max_i - max_of_s; i--)  
    {  
        for(j = max_j; j > max_j - max_of_s; j--)
```

You mixed maxi and maxs.

Let me additionally explain that the C++ code on GeeksForGeeks is mostly horrible. Very often the C++ page is a one to one copy from C. Maybe adding on C++ statement like `std::cout`. But has nothing to do with C++

The presented code for this solution is extraordinary bad C++ code and should not be used, under no circumstance.

With only minor effort, you could convert the bad code in somewhat readable.

PPlease have a look here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 4U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 4U;

void printMaxArea(int (&matrix)[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns]) {

    int subMatrixSums[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns] = {};

    //set 1st column
    for (size_t row = 0U; row < NumberOfRows; ++row)
        subMatrixSums[row][0U] = matrix[row][0U];
    //set 1st row
    for (size_t col = 0U; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col)
        subMatrixSums[0U][col] = matrix[0][col];
    //other entries
    for (size_t row = 1U; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 1U; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {
            if (matrix[row][col] == 1) {
                subMatrixSums[row][col] = std::min(subMatrixSums[row][col - 1U], std::min(subMatrixSums[row - 1U][col], subMatrixSums[row - 1U][col - 1U])) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //maximum entry and index
    int maxSubMatrixSums{ subMatrixSums[0U][0U] };
    int maxRow{};
    int maxCol{};

    for (size_t row = 0U; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 0U; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {
            if (maxSubMatrixSums < subMatrixSums[row][col]) {
                maxSubMatrixSums = subMatrixSums[row][col];
                maxRow = row;
                maxCol = col;
            }
        }
    }
    int area{};
    for (int row = maxRow; row > maxRow- maxSubMatrixSums; --row) {
        for (int col = maxCol; col > maxCol- maxSubMatrixSums; col--) {
            area = area + matrix[row][col];
        }
    }
    std::cout << area;
}

int main() {

    int matrix[NumberOfRows][NumberOfColumns] = { 
        {1,0,0,0},
        {1,0,1,1},
        {1,0,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0} };

    printMaxArea(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Of course there is also a C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

// This function calculates the number of elements, the size, of the biggest square sub matrix.

// It uses a sub matrix for calculating the sums of submatrices
// The algorithm looks at the left, upper, upper-left element and adds 1 to minimum sum of the 3
// As a result, the lower right corner of such a square submatrics will contain the biggest sum

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 4U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfColumns = 4U;
constexpr size_t NumberOfElements = NumberOfRows * NumberOfColumns;

using MyType = int;
using Row = std::array<MyType, NumberOfColumns>;
using Matrix = std::array<Row, NumberOfRows>;

void printSizeMaxSquareSubArea(Matrix &matrix) {

    // Using the sub matrix as a one dimensional array
    std::array<MyType, NumberOfElements> subMatrixSums{};

    // Copy first row
    std::copy(matrix[0].begin(), matrix[0].end(), subMatrixSums.begin());

    // Copy first column
    for (size_t row = 0U; row < NumberOfRows; ++row)
        subMatrixSums[row*NumberOfColumns] = matrix[row][0U];

    // Calculate sums
    for (size_t row = 1U; row < NumberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (size_t col = 1U; col < NumberOfColumns; ++col) {
            if (matrix[row][col] == 1) {
                subMatrixSums[row * NumberOfColumns + col] = 
                    std::min(subMatrixSums[row * NumberOfColumns + col - 1U], 
                    std::min(subMatrixSums[(row - 1U) *NumberOfColumns + col], 
                    subMatrixSums[(row - 1U) * NumberOfColumns + col - 1])) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // Get max value
    const int maxSubMatrixSums = *std::max_element(subMatrixSums.begin(), subMatrixSums.end());
    // Show result
    std::cout << "Size: " << maxSubMatrixSums * maxSubMatrixSums << '\n';
}
// Driver code
int main()
{
    Matrix M{ {
        {1,0,0,0},
        {1,0,1,1},
        {1,0,1,1},
        {0,1,0,0}
    } };
    printSizeMaxSquareSubArea(M);
}
```

Comment: can it give no. of rectangles with 1 or 0